# Is View.generateViewId() unique across libraries?

Tags: android, android-view

If I use `myView.setId(View.generateViewId())` ([View.generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId())) in multiple libraries, is it guaranteed to be unique across all libraries or is the value only guaranteeed to be unique in each library itself?

Answer (score 0):

All these IDs are unique within same ApplicationContext. I'm not sure that methods is thread safe, so pay attention in multithread applications. This method generates very low IDs (usually starting from 1) at Runtime, so if nr.1 is already taken, it will try n.2 and so on until a free number is found.